# How to customise site calendars depending on the event category in SP2010?

Tags: calendar, settings

I have added to the Calendar in the Team site several categories for the events;

1. Meeting
2. Holiday
3. Team Event
4. Business Travel

In order to make this as visual as the Outlook calendar I would like the headers of the event to be shown in different colours depending on the category selected, for example;

1. Meeting - Blue
2. Holiday - Red
3. Team Event - Orange
4. Business Travel - Green.

**UPDATE**: I'm experiencing some trouble with the colour render; attaching the link to the *content editor web part*

Comment: the links on the page are broken. (sad face)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of SharePoint are you using?

In SP 2010, you can use overlays: create a filtered view for each of your categories, then add them as overlays to a calendar view.

My color coding soolution works too, and applies to both SP 2007 and SP 2010. For the most up-to-date tutorial follow this link:

http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2010/04/06/tutorial-add-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-2007-calendar-in-15-minutes/

Comment: Hi @Christophe, thanks a lot for your answer and solution, I have found it very useful. I have just clarified on my question that I'm using SP2010 version and I'm having some trouble rendering the colours. Would you have any other indications that could help me here? Up to this step everything has worked seamlessly :)

Comment: PS. I think should add that I'm quite novice on this so any additional support "for dummies" would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The tutorial has some specific instructions for SP 2010, make sure you use them and not the generic instructions.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't find a way to accomplish this using some simple OOTB setting.
However, I found interesting solution on EndUserSharePoint.com:

http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/04/17/sharepoint-color-coded-calendar-the-payroll-schedule/

The idea is to use calculated columns to display HTML:

http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/

**Caution!** I don't think that described solution is enough secure. Imagine, what if you will place some html in *Title* of an event?... But anyway, it can be a good starting point for creating more secured solution, based on same idea.

Hope, this helps!

Comment: Christophe's solutions are great, check out his Easy Tabs script too,http://sp2010.pathtosharepoint.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Easy-Tabs-v5.aspx.  Absolutely brilliant.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I used the Easy Tabs with MOSS2007, worked perfectly. Great, that Christophe has updated the solution for using with SP2010.

Comment: +1 for your comment on security.