# Changing colors on calendar view

Tags: web-part

I have a calendar list setup. My customer could like to give the appointments in the calendar view (by default green) a different color based on the category; much like the way Outlook does it. I found out that there are different CSS styles for the calender items, which are used when you use the overlay feature.

So I'm now looking for a way to link a certain category for an appointment to one of these CSS classes. I checked the html output, but it seems like custom fields like my category field aren't included in the output. I  thought about using jQuery and a custom serverside service, but that's a lot of work and on top of that the ID isn't available in the HTML (okay, it's included in the hyperlink url, but that's ugly).

I couldn't think of options involving SPD or serverside trick, but perhaps someone here has got a good idea. Of course I know there are third party solutions; but since the ootb web part is 99% ok I'd rather not step out of the box when there's no need to.

Comment: Looks like the same question was already asked recently: 
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11314/can-i-customise-the-team-sites-calendar-depending-on-the-event/11320#11320

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option if you have less than 10 categories: create one view per category, using filters. Then apply the overlay technique to regroup all the views in one calendar.

Comment: Simple but effective, works great; thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at Christophe's [color coded calendar](http://usermanagedsolutions.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Color-Coding-Calendar-List.aspx) solution.  Basically you have a calculated column generate some HTML and use his TexttoHTML script to force the browser to render it.  It's really slick and works client side seamlessly.

Comment: Have you tested this with 2010? We had a similar solution and it does not work for 2010. For 2010 this works better : http://www.orbitone.com/en/blog/archive/2010/10/25/calendar-colour-coding-in-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: We're on 2007, but I have seen people post on other boards it works for them.  They may have rewritten the calculated columns to the 2010 classes though.

Comment: @Shoban: my solution also works on SP 2010 (see the instructions). The post on the orbitone site is good, but contains a couple errors. And Mike Smith's solution doesn't work for every configuration (for the record I have one that is similar to his but I never published it).

Comment: @EricAlexander your link is broken, am not able to get to see anything n the color coded solution. if you have the content, can you pls post it here,it would be helpful for the community.

Comment: http://usermanagedsolutions.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Color-Coding-Calendar-List.aspx